# Is there a way to emulate I2C with Ubuntu on laptop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, i2c

folks.

I am making a program with Python on RaspberryPi2 that installed I2C modules. But I frustrated to write codes using I2C on RaspberryPi, because it is very slow and it cannot use my favorite editor Sublime Text2. I think if I will be able to emulate I2C on my Macbook Air or Ubuntu laptop, I can write codes faster and efficient.

Could you kindly advise me a way to realize my wish?

Comment: Did this answer fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is a way to deploy to the raspberry pi so you can develop locally.  There are a number of different solutions(Git push/ pull, scp, ftp etc..) You should look into `Fabric`[Link](http://www.fabfile.org) api.  This allows you to seamlessly add deployment to your cycle.